# Can I automatically open an Excel workbook and have it refresh without user intervention

Tags: excel

I have a member of staff who wants to display the contents of one of his Excel documents on a big screen for other members to see (but not interact with) and update it several times a day.

I have set up a (windows 10) PC and big screen on the shop floor, it has access to network folders that contain said excel file. It has no keyboard or mouse.

How can I have the PC load the excel file on boot, full screen, preferably in read-only mode so the manager can update it on his laptop, and refresh regularly?

Comment: What about a script that re-opens it every 30 minutes? or 1 hour?

Comment: This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.